# Python Pip Install fails - Could not build the egg. Also cannot use 1.2.5 because of google cloud sql

Tags: python, mysql, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I need mysql-python.

I get error of could not build egg while installing 1.2.4
Everywhere it says install 1.2.5, which works for me too.

But googleAppEngine's app.yaml supports only 1.2.4

```
libraries:
- name: MySQLdb
  version: "1.2.4"
```

So if I use 1.2.4 there, and 1.2.5 in the virtual env, I get the error -

```
ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: this is MySQLdb version (1, 2, 5, 'final', 1), but _mysql is version (1, 2, 4, 'final', 1)
    1:1430668397.857531 This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.
```

What is supposed to be done, either working with App engine or with 1.2.4 pip will do!

Comment: This `libraries:
- name: MySQLdb
  version: "latest"` does any change?

Comment: I saw from your last question that from the paths you seem to be using MacOS. In your case you'd need Xcode and the MySQL headers to build mysql-python from pip (needs C extension). Alternatively installing mysql-python using homebrew (http://brew.sh/) may work.

Comment: With app engine unfortunately you are stuck with using the included versions of some third party libraries such as mysql-python, as they will not let you include native binaries with your app (only python source and *.pyc files).

Comment: No, MySQLdb version:"latest" didn't help. Also, I tried installing homebrew didn't work, the only solution was to pip uninstall mysql-python, and upload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run -

pip uninstall mysql-python

```
YAML - 
    libraries:
    - name: MySQLdb
      version: "1.2.4"
```

Settings -

```
    'default': {
        'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'HOST':'/cloudsql/ProjectName:DBName',
        'NAME': 'my_database',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '********',
}
```

Answer (score 0):

run `pip install --upgrade setuptools` then try `pip install mysql-python`